# How to tell if SNS will allow publishing

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How can a script determine whether an SNS topic can be published to (i.e. the permissions of a key or profile will allow it) without actually publishing to it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no possible way of testing in advance if the AWS role you're using is allowed to publish. Some AWS commands for specific services (e.g. EC2) accept the `--dry-run` flag to test a request, but SNS has no such option.

Your best option would be to try publishing the message and catching 403 HTTP errors. If ever your call is unauthorized, I believe you will not be charged (source [for SQS, but I imagine SNS billing has a similar policy]: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=127609)